# Linker requires versions of compiler and Boost in the names of lib-files. fatal error LNK1104

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

To install boost I run

```
b2 install optimization=speed variant=debug,release --layout=tagged --prefix=BOOST_DIR
```

Names of lib-files look like

```
...
libboost_serialization-mt.lib
libboost_serialization-mt-gd.lib
...
```

When project is linking I get error

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_serialization-vc140-mt-gd-1_62.lib'

This file is not set in project settings with any names, only directory of this file is set. The project is linking successfully if I add compiler and Boost versions to the file name.
Can I make the project no need of Boost lib-files renaming when I install new version of Boost?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When building boost with the `--layout=tagged` option, you have to define `BOOST_AUTO_LINK_TAGGED` before including any boost header to allow auto-linking to work correctly.  Otherwise, disable auto-linking by defining `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` and explicitly specify the library.